# Access command line arguments in springboot in thread

Tags: java, spring-boot

I run my spring boot application with

mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="test1, test2, test3"

I need this 3 arguments in my runnable. How can i access them in my Compressor runnable class? It prints null.

```
@Configuration
    public class MultiThreadConfig {

        @Bean
        public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
            return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor(); // Or use another one of your liking
        }

        @Bean
        public CommandLineRunner schedulingRunner(TaskExecutor executor) {
            return new CommandLineRunner() {
                public void run(String[] args) throws Exception {
                    executor.execute(new Compressor(args));
                }
            };
        }
    }



public class Compressor implements Runnable {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationArguments appArgs;

    String[] args;

    // Constructor
    public Compressor(String[] args) {
        //Initialization of atributes
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("COMPRESSOR YO");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
        System.out.println(appArgs);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because you are are creating your own instance of `Compressor` with `new Compressor(args)` and you are autowiring in `ApplicationArguments`. You cannot autowire in objects that you create yourself with `new`; autowiring only works in Spring beans. Make `Compressor` a `@Component` and inject it in method `schedulingRunner` instead of creating an instance yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jesper pointed out you are creating the `Compressor` object by yourself using `new` keyword so the `ApplicationArguments` will not be autowired as this instance of `Compressor` is not managed by Spring. The solution is to create a bean for `Compressor` object and let it be managed by Spring. For example :

```
@Configuration
public class MultiThreadConfig {

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor(); // Or use another one of your liking
    }


    @Bean
    public Compressor compressor(ApplicationArguments applicationArguments) {
        return Compressor(applicationArguments);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner schedulingRunner(TaskExecutor executor, Compressor compressor) {
        return new CommandLineRunner() {
            public void run(String[] args) throws Exception {
                executor.execute(compressor);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Compressor implements Runnable {

    private final ApplicationArguments appArgs;
    private final String[] args;

    @Autowired
    public Compressor(ApplicationArguments applicationArguments) {
        appArgs = applicationArguments;
        args = applicationArguments.getSourceArgs();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("COMPRESSOR YO");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
    }
}
```

Note here that I am using constructor injection instead of field injections which is typically better option.

If you do not want to crate a bean in configuration you could also mark Compressor with Spring stereotype :

```
@Component
public class Compressor implements Runnable {

    private final ApplicationArguments appArgs;
    private final String[] args;

    public Compressor(ApplicationArguments applicationArguments) {
        appArgs = applicationArguments;
        args = applicationArguments.getSourceArgs();
    }
    //...
}
```

and use instance of it in your configuration like shown above :

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner schedulingRunner(TaskExecutor executor, Compressor compressor) {
    //...
}
```